# Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) or (using password: NO)?

Tags: mysql, database

I have installed mysql in mac big sur using homebrew as

```
brew install mysql
```

But during the

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEDGE

I mistakenly gave some other password to root and thus not able to start mysql again.

Tried all the steps/ suggestions for this question all over stack-overflow and blogs but did not get full steps anywhere (probably I might have missed it somewhere)

I tried to stop mysql and then start with --skip-grant-tables but it is still giving me same error for the second command.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but upto no progress so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going through multiple answers I found this steps which worked for me

Mac OS : Big Sur 11.6.8
MySQL : 8.0.30

Steps:

1. Uninstall mysql. (In my case I am using homebrew)

> brew uninstall mysql

2. Reinstall mysql

> brew install mysql

3. Goto path and open the file in editor

> /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

4. Copy this in the file

> [mysqld]
>
> skip-grant-tables

(You might already have the "mysqld" section so just add the line below it)

5. Goto terminal
6. Stop mysql service if running

> mysql.server stop

7. Run the command

> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking

8. Start mysql as you won't have to enter password again now

> mysql -u root